# Не видит путь к файлу при отправке через intent

Tags: java, android

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName()
                        + "/drawable/" + "computer.png");
  Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
  shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Text");
  shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
  shareIntent.setType("image/png");
  shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
  startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "send"));
 }
});
```

хочу отправить изображение + текст по неявным интентом. При отправки в gmail, пишет,что пустой файл. В чем проблема?

Comment: Вы добавили permission read external storage?

Comment: Да, добавлял все разрешение